# How to get Intellij to put copyright on python files

Tags: python, templates, intellij-idea

I am trying to update my Intellij Python project with copyright headers.  I am using Intellij 15 and have set up the copyright profile according to the documentation.   When I use the Intellij "update copyright" feature, only files that have a copyright formatting component specified are update.  So my XML files all get copyrights, but my python files do not.  The problem is, there doesn't seem to by any way to add a formatting component for python.

One thing I tried was to uncheck the "use block comment" since python doesn't have that, and it didn't make a difference.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time copyright notices in IntelliJ IDEA do not support Python code. [Related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9915)

Comment: Any chance on getting this soon?

Comment: It's 2018 (halfway through) and the feature still isn't there... Just spent half an hour trying to make it work :/